# view in GridView can be focused, but it doesn't call onFocusChange() method

Tags: android, gridview

There is a `GridView`, and a adapter extends `baseAdapter`, which I defined myself, and in the adapter class, I override the function of `getView()`, there comes the question that,the view in the `GridView` can be focused, but it can not call `onFocusChange()` method, I don't know why, as the code is too long, I didn't paste it here.

Thank you . 
There is my getView method below

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HashMap<String, Object> appInfo = mAppList.get(position);
    CVButtons view ;
    if(convertView == null){
        view = new CVButtons(parent.getContext());
    }
    else{
        view = (CVButtons) convertView;
    }

    view.setImageDrawable((Drawable)appInfo.get("ItemImage"));
    view.setTextString((String)appInfo.get("ItemText"));
    view.setImageParams(75, 75);
    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setID(position);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setEnabled(true);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = ((CVButtons)v).getID();
                HashMap<String, Object> item = mAppList.get(id);
                startActivity((String) item.get("ItemText"));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Even if your code is too long, it would be better if you paste it, because it's too difficult to try to recognize the problem without the code. Paste just `getView()` method snippet.

Comment: there is my getView method below

Comment: I have already solve the problem ,that I have thought that when set parent view focausable to false , then it's child view will not requestFoucse...so I set GridView 's attribute of focausable to ture ,and now I set it to false. and all it works.

Comment: From your listed code I can suppose, that `CVButtons` is composite view, so probably, some of it's child view in fact call onFocusedChanged() method. Is it possible to check my supposal?

Comment: yes CVButtons is a composite view , and the problem has been solved , it is caused by the GridView , I set it can not get focused , and it  work well, but when the GridView can get focus ,the child of it can not get focus which is the situation I  don't want to see @teoREtik

Comment: @zyunchen if you already have the answer. post it as an answer and accept it as the correct answer to help the people who visit in future . thanks